# Browser compatible NodeJS templating

Tags: node.js, haml

I am looking to reuse templates I write for NodeJS in the browser, by this I hope to gain fast page loading time (initial rendering), and dynamic content switching ability, etc...

This would be most natural on Node, any ideas of compatible templating engines?

By the way, I like the HAML style syntax, so anything HAML based is a huge plus.

Thanks!
Roman

Edit: 
I think that I like the approach of Mustache the most, it works with Express and also in client side.. will update here on how the implementation went..

Answer (score 11):

[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) is excellent, very similar to HAML and compiles down to JavaScript for browser usage :)

See the README on the [Github repo](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) for details.

Jade is also the semi-officially recommended template language for the currently most popular web framework for Node, [Express](http://expressjs.com/) (in fact, they share authors), so it looks like a solid choice to me.

I recently evaluated a lot of NodeJS template libraries and ended up picking Jade.

I've made a [simple example of using Jade in the browser](http://reveal.dk/misc/jade/). The fun stuff happens in [demo.js](http://reveal.dk/misc/jade/demo.js), and you can also view [index.jade](http://reveal.dk/misc/jade/index.jade) which contains the basic page markup.

Comment: Could you link some examples of using `Jade` in the browser and what the API looks like.

Comment: I’ve added a [small example](http://reveal.dk/misc/jade/), as mentioned in the answer above :)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that Jade does not work in FF3 (according to the list), also it doesnt work on the iPad =/

Answer (score 2):

[EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) works in the browser and with express out of the box. Admittedly the syntax is not HANL style nor is particularly feature rich but you can easily get it to work.

I've also used a [simple technique](http://gamewithnodejs.blogspot.com/2011/04/setting-up-simple-blog-part-1.html) to re-use templates and views on both client and server and it works reasonably well

Answer (score 1):

[JAVASCRIPT TEMPLATE SHOWDOWN!~](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/73)

Which is pretty much all the best templates lined up to test in the browser.

(also @Raynos it includes an example of jade in the browser)

Personally I use Jade, combined with stylus and jquery I only use css selectors.

But. . . as you can see from the chart Jade doesn't get along with firefox 3 or opera.

Comment: My example above works fine in all the browsers I have (tried both Opera 10 and 11). I do not have FF3, though, so I can't vouch for that.

Comment: As for the rendering speed, I don't think I'll make much of a difference in most apps, as inserting the rendered markup in the DOM takes much longer than any of the template enginges do rendering, not to mention the time spent getting the data to render in the first place.
One is of course entitled to use whatever template library he wishes, but I see little reason to sacrifice convenience for dubious performance gains :)

Comment: Nor does it get along with the iPad, and as much as I would love to ignore apple, I cant :(

Comment: Are there any results for Google Chrome (which should be comparable to node.js speed)? The site doesn't work in any browser I used. Only the old revision 1 was OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could try weld https://github.com/hij1nx/weld that has implementation in server side and client side.

Answer (score 0):

[node-jqtpl](http://github.com/kof/node-jqtpl) is your best bet. It's a port of [jQuery Templates](http://api.jQuery.com/category/plugins/templates/), so 100% reusable in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command-like utility TplCpl written in Node.js that allows to compile Jade templates for browser use.

https://github.com/jsmarkus/tplcpl